Indent format of algorithm2e in revtex4-1
When I use algorithm2e package to write a paper in vertex 4-1 with WinEdt7, the output pdf file has a wrong indent format in the algorithm part. Everything is messed up! It looks like this:

What could possibly be the reason?
Here is part of my code:
\documentclass[twocolumn,pra,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Gram-Schmidt Process for Vector Set Orthogonal Normalization~\cite{horn2012matrix,bhatia2013matrix}}
\label{alg1}
\KwIn{$S=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{m}\}$, $a_i\in \mathbb{C}^n$}
\KwOut{$U=\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_{t}\}$, satisfying $u_j^{\dagger}u_i=\delta_{ij}$, $\forall i, j$, $span\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{m}\}=span\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_{t}\}$}
\BlankLine
$v\gets a_1/||a_1||$\;
$U\gets \{v\}$\;
    \For{$k\leftarrow2$ \textbf{to} $m$}{
     $v\gets a_k$;\\
    \For{$u_j$ \textbf{in} $U$}{
    $v\gets v-u_j^{\dagger} a_ku_j$;
}
    \If{$||v||>0$}{
    $U\gets U\cup\{v/||v||\}$;
}
}
\end{algorithm}

Please help me!!! Anyone who can answer my questions is greatly appreciated!!!

Use revtex4-2.

My tutor asked me to use revtex4-1. TAT. My code runs prefectly in revtex4-2

If you must use revtex4-1 then add \normalsize after \documentclass.

@mingo Tell your tutor that revtex4-1 only exists for backwards compatibility and that revtex4-2 was released in January 2019.

This is basically the same situation as in Parskip doesn't work. The horizontal skips are fixed by the algorithm2e package
% algorithm2e.sty lines 1600--1604
\newcommand{\SetInd}[2]{%
\skiprule=#1%
\skiptext=#2%
\skiplength=\skiptext\advance\skiplength by \skiprule\advance\skiplength by 0.4pt}%
\SetInd{0.5em}{1em}

The trouble is that revtex4-1 does not issue \normalsize in its code, so in the preamble the font is still \nullfont and the corresponding em is just zero. algorithm2e should better wrap the last line in a \AtBeginDocument hook.
You should use revtex4-2; the differences are mostly cosmetic and I haven't heard of any backward compatibility problem, so there is no real reason to use revtex4-1 for new documents.
If for some reason you can't, then you can add explicitly \normalsize after \documentclass{revtex4-1}. Alternatively, you could do what algorithm2e should be doing from the start, namely delaying the setting. So use either
\documentclass[...]{revtex4-1}
\normalsize
\usepackage[...]{algorithm2e}

or (IMO better)
\documentclass[...]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[...]{algorithm2e}
\AtBeginDocument{\SetInd{0.5em}{1em}}


OMG it worked! Thank you very very much!!
